# Show Metabox In Write Post/Page When Template is Changed

Tags: wordpress, templates, meta-boxes

I can create the metaboxes just fine and if I assign a metabox to a specific template(s), they appear just fine in the Add New Page screen, but only after the new page has been saved.

Is there a way to show/hide the metabox when the template value has changed...without having to save the page first?

Answer (score 0):

**Add to WP admin page**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#page_template").live('change',function(){

    var getCurrentTemplate = $("#page_template").val(); 

    if( getCurrentTemplate == "template-contact.php"){

            $("#pageheading-hide").attr('checked', true);
            $("#pageheading").css({'display':'block'});
    }
    else{
        $("#pageheading-hide").attr('checked', false);
        $("#pageheading").css({'display':'none'});
    }

});

});
```